# jQuery $(this) works in Firefox; fails the second time in Internet Explorer?

Tags: jquery

My little jQuery snippet works great in Firefox; but fails in IE.  This is particularly annoying and mysterious because a very similar command, just a few lines earlier, does work in IE.  Any ideas?

```
$('.bio_text').clone()
   .each ( function(index, value) {
     name = $(this).find('.lc_name').text();
       // Prior line works just fine

     name = '<span class="lc_name">' + name + '</span>';
     title = $(this).find('.lc_title').text();
       // Prior line fails in IE and doesn't execute anything further,
       //  as determined by sprinkling alert() statements after every line

     title = '<div class="lc_title">' + title + '</div>';
     $('<li>' + name + title + '</li>').appendTo('ul#nav_team');
    });
```

Comment: Could you post some markup as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internet Explorer will throw errors if you don't declare variables before assigning values to them.

You might want to try declaring your variables like this

```
   ...
   var name = $(this).find('.lc_name').text();
   ...
   var title = $(this).find('.lc_title').text();
   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Could `$(this).find('.lc_title').` be returning multiple items (or no items) and therefore effecting the `.text()` funciton? Just a thought...

Could be worth seperating out the line and inspecting what is being brought back (F12 in IE8).

Comment: According to the online manual, "The result of the .text() method is a string containing the combined text of all matched elements." - so even if it were matching multiple elements there should be no problem...

Comment: I voted the answer up for the helpful suggestion to find the IE debugger, which I didn't know existed - thanks!